# Data from Firebase shows after the View Loader has loaded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The following view controller loads before the Firebase data has a chance to load. How do I make it so that the Firebase data loads alongside or before the view loader shows up?

When I use breakpoints, I can see that the new view appears and THEN the data is pulled from Firebase. I need the data to be loaded from Firebase before the view appears.

This is the code for the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout",
                                                       style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

    let image = UIImage(named: "new_message_icon")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNewMessage))

    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
}

@objc func handleNewMessage(){

    let newMessageController = NewMessageController()

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newMessageController)

    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil,
                        afterDelay: 0)
    }else{
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

            }

            },withCancel: nil)

    }

}
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
}

}
```

Comment: For That you should call Data from preview Viewcontroller and ones you got store that in locally and then open your viewcontroller

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Is there something specific that's not functioning? As it is, you're loading a minute amount of data from Firebase when the view loads from the xib and before viewWillAppear. It doesn't look like there would be any issues - perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: Yes but I would like for the new view that appears to load after all of the data is pulled from Firebase. Currently the Firebase data is being pulled after the new view has loaded. See what I mean?